# How to align numbers by decimal position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alignment, numeric

My table:

```
  2       4,5   100    400
  3        20    10    100
4,2    10.000   500    600
9,2  10.024,5   610  1.100

mylist = [['2', '4,5', '100', '400'], ['3', '20', '10', '100'], ['4,2', '10.000', '500', '600'], ['9,2', '10.024,5', '610', '1.100']]
```

How can I align the numbers like this:

```
2         4,5  100    400
3        20     10    100
4,2  10.000    500    600
9,2  10.024,5  610  1.100
```

What I did:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
    '{:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10}'.format(mylist[i][0], mylist[i][1], mylist[i][2], mylist[i][3])
```

This gives above results as in the 1st table but the decimals are not aligned.

**Update**
I adapted the solution of Francisco to the length of the elements in whatever list.

```
mylist = [['1300', '300', '300'], ['2300,5', '300,5', '300,5'], ['3600000000000', '6000000', '6000000'], ['4200,2345', '200,2345', '200,2345'], ['5301', '301', '301'], ['6200', '200', '200'], ['7300', '300', '300000000'], ['8300,5', '300,500000', '300,5'], ['960000', '600', '6000'], ['10200,2345', '200999,2345', '200,2345'], ['11301', '301', '301'], ['12200', '200', '200'], ['13300', '300', '300'], ['14300,5', '300,5', '300,5']]

column2row = zip(*mylist)
maxbefore = []
maxafter = []
for m in column2row:
    maxlengthbefore = 0
    maxlengthafter  = 0
    for e in m:
        if ',' in e:
           lengthbefore = len(str(e).split(",")[0])
           if lengthbefore > maxlengthbefore:
              maxlengthbefore = lengthbefore
           lengthafter  = len(str(e).split(",")[1])
           if lengthafter > maxlengthafter:
              maxlengthafter = lengthafter
        else:
           lengthbefore = len(str(e))
           if lengthbefore > maxlengthbefore:
              maxlengthbefore = lengthbefore
    maxbefore.append(maxlengthbefore)
    maxafter.append(maxlengthafter + 1)

for m in mylist:
    r = 0
    for e in m:
        if ',' in e:
            print(e.rjust(int(maxbefore[r]) + len(e) - e.index(',')).ljust(int(maxbefore[r])+int(maxafter[r])), end=' ')
        else:
            print(e.rjust(int(maxbefore[r])).ljust(int(maxbefore[r])+int(maxafter[r])), end=' ')
        r += 1
    print()
```

**Output**

```
         1300          300              300      
         2300,5        300,5            300,5    
3600000000000      6000000          6000000      
         4200,2345     200,2345         200,2345 
         5301          301              301      
         6200          200              200      
         7300          300        300000000      
         8300,5        300,500000       300,5    
       960000          600             6000      
        10200,2345  200999,2345         200,2345 
        11301          301              301      
        12200          200              200      
        13300          300              300      
        14300,5        300,5            300,5
```

Comment: You seem to be treating `,` as the decimal separator, but then there is a `.` in the last row of the last column ... I take it that `.` doesn't get special treatment here?

Comment: @mgilson, I use west-european formatting. Decimals = ',' and Thousands = '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for m in mylist:
    for e in m:
        if ',' in e:
            print(e.rjust(10 + len(e) - e.index(',')).ljust(15), end=' ')
        else:
            print(e.rjust(10).ljust(15), end=' ')
    print()
```

prints:

```
         2               4,5           100             400     
         3              20              10             100     
         4,2        10.000             500             600     
         9,2        10.024,5           610           1.100
```

Basically what it does is check if the string has a comma in it.

If it does it checks its place, centers the string to the right checking how many characters there are without counting everything after the comma, and then centers it to the left this time counting the places after the comma.

If there aren't commas in the string it just centers it to the left and to the right.

Comment: Francisco, It doesn't work on my system (python3). A lot of error.`<built-in function print>
         4,2   
(None,)
    10.000     
(None,)
       500     
(None,)
       600     
(None,)`

Comment: Sorry about that, there I made it work with python 3

Comment: I suppose there is no solution to my question?

Comment: @Reman How doesn't my answer solves your problem?, you can change the numbers inside `ljust` and `rjust` to change the amount of spaces.

Comment: Francisco, thank you very much. I didn't see you update :) Very nice. Can you please explain a bit more what you've done?

Comment: Francisco, the table is not aligned when there are long numbers in mylist p.e. `96000000000` or longer

Comment: @Reman that long number won't work because it's longer than 10 characters (the number inside the `rjust` call), just make that number bigger, in this case `>= 11`. I also added a brief explanation

Comment: Francisco, I just want 1 or 2 spaces between the columns and I tried to adapt your solution to the length of the elements in the list (which can be different in every list). I updated your solution. What did I wrong? I still don't capture totally what you're doing.

Comment: You never increase `r` on the loop, and you have to change `maxafter.append(maxlengteafter)` to `maxafter.append(maxlengteafter + 1)`

Comment: Francisco, I forgot to copy the loop increaser. But something doesn't work. The spaces between the column are not correct. Please try p.e. this list: `[['1300', '300', '300'], ['2300,5', '300,5', '300,5'], ['3600000000000', '6000000', '6000000'], ['4200,2345', '200,2345', '200,2345'], ['5301', '301', '301'], ['6200', '200', '200'], ['7300', '300', '300000000'], ['8300,5', '300,500000', '300,5'], ['960000', '600', '6000'], ['10200,2345', '200999,2345', '200,2345'], ['11301', '301', '301'], ['12200', '200', '200'], ['13300', '300', '300'], ['14300,5', '300,5', '300,5']]`

Comment: Looks fine to me https://gist.github.com/franciscouzo/0ead6c32d29cb1d1ada2fd3cd0db2fbf

Comment: thank you very much! My `r=0` was placed after `for e in m:`. It had to be places before `for e in m:`. Now it works fine. Thank you for the time dedicated to my problem :)

Comment: Francisco, Hope you don't mind if I ask you one more question. If a column is shorter then another column, the whole alignment crashes. p.e. `mylist =[['300', '200,5', '4000'], ['0,34', '0,4', '12.000'], ['3002', '2', '44'], ['200', '12']]` It gives an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(e.rjust(int(maxbefore[r])).ljust(int(maxbefore[r])+int(maxafter[r])), end=' ')
IndexError: list index out of range` Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to happen, do you want it just to skip it at the end? The easiest way would be to append empty strings to the lists missing elements

Comment: Yes, I just want to skip it.

Comment: What do you think is the right way to find out which field is empty? Or add the empty field always at the end if a column is shorter then the others?

Comment: Yeah, just get the length of the longest list, and pad the ones with missing elements

Comment: :) yes that is what I did. But the sorting is wrong. If the middle column is shorter, adding empty elements and do an alignment, the elements of the 3rd column is moved to the 2column. Well no problem. I don't want to ask you more stuff not directly connected to my question.